# Select specific data from R DataTable in Shiny with checkboxes and create histogram

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a data table with DT in Shiny that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to select data with checkboxes on a side panel that satisfies certain attributes (e.g. Mfr=Mitsubish, Joint=1, etc.) and then updates a histogram of deg/s in real time to view.

I've read through the material I could find on the web, but I can't figure out how to do this.  Does anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@guero64 Here is an example I had that I believe has examples of what you're looking for. I hope this is helpful. It is based on the `diamonds` dataset and has a couple of `checkbox` filters you can apply to the data.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Example"),

  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput("cb_cut", "Cut (Ideal)", FALSE),
    checkboxInput("cb_color", "Color (I)", FALSE)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("data_table"),
    plotOutput("data_plot")
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    dat <- diamonds
    if (input$cb_cut) { dat <- dat %>% filter(dat$cut %in% "Ideal") }
    if (input$cb_color) { dat <- dat %>% filter(dat$color %in% "I") }
    dat
  })

  output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    filtered_data()
  })

  output$data_plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(filtered_data()$price, main = "Distribution of Price", ylab = "Price")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```